# How to update metadata tags using Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I want to be able to do a lookup on managed metadata to pick up values from other fields that would be populated by power automate.

This lookup on managed metadata will be on multiple lists across several site collections.

I will have to create a list of "lists" to check everyday to see where the metadata tags are used and update across the different site collections.

QUESTION is power automate the right way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use power automate to update the item in "lists" value when managed metadata column value has been changed.

The general flow is like below, notice that "11" is a single text column, "manage" is a managed metadata column. As to the ID in update item step, you could replace it as you need:

[image]

As a result, when I create a column in list, "11" in MS list will be updated.

[image]

Comment: Hi, David, do you have any further questions about this thread? If you have any questions or progress, you can contact me in time.